# Multiple monitors get mixed up

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, displayport

I am on OSX Lion, with a MacBook Pro. I am using the DisplayPort for an external monitor and two USB Diamond BVU195 for two extra monitors. Each time when I turn my computer on, the two monitors get mixed up/reversed - so instead of going from left to right, like this:

```
MBP Screen  |  BVU195 - 1  |  DisplayPort  |  BVU195 - 2
```

It shows up **wrong** like this:

```
MBP Screen  |  BVU195 - 2  |  DisplayPort  |  BVU195 - 1
```

It is easily fixable by going to System Preferences and reversing them, but next reboot, they are mixed up again.

Comment: If you ever resolved this, those of us with the same problem could benefit from you answering your own question